# Combining difference-in-differences and fixed effects

Tags: fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I've seen several related posts to this topic here and elsewhere (e.g. [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1323707-fixed-effect-difference-in-differences-model)). However, after reading through them I'm still somewhat confused on why we would want to combine DID with fixed effects.

As I understand DID and fixed effects, the former is a variant of the latter, so combining them in one model seem unneccesary. On the other hand, I have a DID-model that changes effect size (and other parameters) when specifying the model as a DID fixed effects model. (The model does have some covariates.)

I have searched for this several times to avoid unnecessary posting, but I can't find a clear explanation motivating the combination of DID and fixed effects. A short explanation or relevant references would be very helpful.

Comment: Suppose model for DID is a model with 4 fixed effects (parameters). Correct? What is your other fixed effects to be combined (added into model)?

Comment: In my case I'm evaluating a programme which switches on at same time for all treatment units, so I have a pre-post*treatment interaction term. I've added two theoretically motivated covariates. If I understand you correctly, adding fixed effects to DID ensures that the effects of these are constant over time?

Comment: Given "a programme which switches on at same time for all treatment units", where does DID come from? DID means (A-B)-(C-D). In your DID what is A, B, C,D?

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear, but I was just trying to make it clear that it's not a staggered design where treatment switches on at different times within the treatment group. So, A-B is the pre-post difference in outcome of interest for the treatment group, while C-D is the pre-post difference for the control group. Maybe I'm just not getting this, but I'm not quite sure how this addresses the addition of fixed-effects question?

Comment: So the fixed effects for DID come from pre/post and treatment/control. What other fixed effects do you want to add to the model?

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. DID gives the fixed effect for treatment. I'm adding two unit-specific time-varying covariates, and need to specify them as fixed effects to obtain the fixed effects of these?